# Facebook messenger platform webhook Verify Token not validated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I've created a facebook app on [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com)
I've setup a local rails server and exposed it to public internet using ngrok. I'm receiving facebook's webhook validation `GET` request and I'm returning the `hub_challenge` code in response. The response `status code` is also `200`. I've provided a secret `Verify Token` which is required to set up a messenger webhook. But after all this I'm getting error

> The Callback URL or Verify Token couldn't be validated. Please verify
> the provided information or try again later.

I've checked that the request is received and the response being sent back to the facebook server, but don't know why it fails and says `Verify Token` couldn't be validated. Is it some special token that I have to get from somewhere from facebook messenger platform? Currently I've provided it my own secret token. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The Verify Token you set yourself in your app dashboard. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#configure-webhooks-product

Comment: I'm providing the token but it still doesnt accept it

Comment: Validating the token happens on your end only, that is a step to make sure that the validation request came from Facebook, and not somewhere else. As long as you respond with the proper status code and send the hub_challenge value back, this should work.

Comment: yup turns out that it was hub.message which needs to be sent back. I was sending hub_message.

Answer (score 1):

when I verify Facebook Webhook with my website i got that kind error

```
 The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="1421256154", received="1421256154\u003Clink rel=..."
```

My code

```
public function verify_token(Request $request)
{
    $mode  = $request->get('hub_mode');
    $token = $request->get('hub_verify_token');
    $challenge = $request->get('hub_challenge');

    if ($mode === "subscribe" && $this->token and $token === $this->token) {
        return response($challenge,200);
    }
    return response("Invalid token!", 400);
}
```

my code everything is ok .I am using laravel thats why `APP_DEBUG=true` defalt when I change it `APP_DEBUG=false` its working and my problem solved.